# Getting the XPath from an HTML document

Tags: python, html, xpath, python-requests

https://next.newsimpact.com/NewsWidget/Live

I am trying to code a python script that will grab a value from a HTML table in the link above. The link above is the site that I am trying to grab from, and this is the code I have written. I think that possibly my XPath is incorrect, because its been doing fine on other elements, but the path I'm using is not returning/printing anything.

```
from lxml import html
import requests
page = requests.get('https://next.newsimpact.com/NewsWidget/Live')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

#This will create a list of buyers:
value = tree.xpath('//*[@id="table9521"]/tr[1]/td[4]/text()')

print('Value: ', value)
```

What is strange is when I open the view source code page, I cant find the table I am trying to pull from.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: 2,632 @GillesQuenot

Comment: Put also your 'import' lines

Comment: Oops, I included them in the code now. @GillesQuenot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Required data absent in initial page source - it comes from XHR. You can get it as below:

```
import requests

response = requests.get('https://next.newsimpact.com/NewsWidget/GetNextEvents?offset=-120').json()

first_previous = response['Items'][0]['Previous']  # Current output - "2.632"
second_previous = response['Items'][1]['Previous']  # Currently - "0.2"
first_forecast = response['Items'][0]['Forecast']  # ""
second_forecast = response['Items'][1]['Forecast']  # "0.3"
```

You can parse `response` as simple Python dict and get all required data

Comment: You have no idea the amount of help you've given me... Lol, been so stuck on this. I had no idea you could use JSON for this, shows my knowledge on the stuff.. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is simple, `request` don't handle [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) at all. The values are JS generated !

If you really need to run this [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath), you need to use a module capable of understanding JS, like [spynner](/questions/tagged/spynner).

You can test when you need JS or not by first using [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) or by disabling JS in your browser. With firefox : `about:config` in navigation bar, then search `javascript.enabled`, then double click on it to switch between true or false

In [chrome](/questions/tagged/chrome), open chrome dev tools, there's the option somewhere.

Check https://github.com/makinacorpus/spynner

Another (possible) problem, use `tree = html.fromstring(page.text)` not `tree = html.fromstring(page.content)`

Comment: Oh, I see... Sorry about that. Do you have any suggestions how to go about obtaining the data then? Are you saying that using XPath is not a good method?